# Assigning negative numbers to unsigned char doesn't cause compilation error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Shouldn't I receive an error message for doing this?

```
  unsigned char n = -500;
  //or this
  Byte n = -500;
```

This shouldn't even compile!

Comment: The compiler simply converts the value to fit in the allotted space. There is probably a warning that can be enabled to catch this. But be prepared for a flood of new warnings.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. When I type 'unsigned' I clearly mean NO negative values. Right?

Comment: `char` stores a value from -128 to 127. `unsigned char` stores 0 to 255. The -500 is simply converted to fit in the range 0 to 255. Of course during this conversion its value is essentially turned into a useless value. But simply making a variable `unsigned` in no way prevents you from assigning negative values.

Comment: BTW - this is really a basic question from the C language. I'm sure some searching on the topic will turn up much better explanations.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169692/assigning-negative-numbers-to-an-unsigned-int

Answer (score 4):

Enable SIGN_COMPARE from Build Settings of your target and test.

[image]

Comment: Turning this on will likely result in many new warnings flooding the next build.