# Signed and Unsigned program error

Tags: c

So today am learning about the signed and unsigned variables. So what i can make out is that signed can have positive, negative and zero values and unsigned can have only the positive values.
So to try this through code i wrote this program in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
    int a=-10;
    unsigned int x=-4;
    printf("signed variable value is : %d\n Unsigned variable value is : %u",a,x);


}
```

SO as per my expectation output should be like this :

```
signed variable value is : -10
Unsigned variable value is : 4
```

But in reality it turned out to be like this:

```
signed variable value is : -10
Unsigned variable value is : 4294967292
```

Can any one explain this !!

Comment: it should be warning.. but some times 2^32 (range of an unsigned int ) - 4 = 4294967296 - 4 = 4294967292

Comment: @rabishaw there should not be a warning, this is how `unsigned int` is supposed to behave

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a negative value into a `unsigned int` and print it using the format specifier `%u`, 2's complement of that number will be taken into consideration.
So that `x` become 2's complement of -4, ie `4294967292`

A similar question is asked here
[Assigning negative numbers to an unsigned int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169692/assigning-negative-numbers-to-an-unsigned-int)

Comment: The link is different, it is asking about undefined behaviour caused by using the wrong format specifier

Comment: @MattMcNabb
Just go through the answers. You can find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The way that `unsigned` variables work is that they wrap around past 0 (both going forward and back), treating 0 as congruent to 2<sup>32</sup> (on a 32-bit system). To see this, try the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int test = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
         test = test - 1;
         printf("%u\n", test);
    }
}
```

Output (on a 32-bit system):

```
2
1
0
4294967295
4294967294
4294967293
4294967292
4294967291
4294967290
4294967289
```

Back to your code. `-4` is of course the same as `0 - 4` so what you have gotten is the fourth item past `0` on this list.

<sup>NB. Your code does not have any errors apart from [void main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

The unsigned variable doesn't take the absolute value for you.

Since you are putting a negative value in it, it casts the signed integer value (-4) to a 4 byte unsigned variable.

I am guessing the negative values are stored as 2's complement here. Therefore what you get as a -4 on a unsigned 4byte variable is in fact 2^32 -4 (one wrap around) : 4294967292