# Why does printf show negative values for unsigned int?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsigned long with negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455806/unsigned-long-with-negative-value)

I have written one kernel module which interrupts any system call, prints its current user_id and input parameters passed to the system call function. Among them, one is sys_ioctl() as below:

```
asmlinkage long sys_ioctl(unsigned int fd, unsigned int cmd,unsigned long arg);
```

which means all input parameters are unsigned int numbers.

But when I print input parameters, I get the following output:

```
 fd=21, cmd=-1072143871 and arg=3202983648 
 fd=21, cmd=-1072143871 and arg=3202983648 
 fd=21, cmd=-1072143871 and arg=3202983648 
 ----------
```

Here is my function definition:

```
asmlinkage long our_sys_ioctl(unsigned int fd ,  unsigned int cmd , unsigned long arg)
{
    uid_t gtuid ;
    gtuid = getuid_call();
    printk ("our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = %d with fd=%i, cmd=%i and arg=%lu \n ", gtuid, fd, cmd, arg);
    return original_call_ioctl(fd , cmd , arg);
}
```

Any idea why cmd value is negative and what these values mean?

Comment: How are you printing the values?

Comment: How do you print your numbers? Maybe you're implicitly casting them to signed integers again?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: Don't you get a warning for "mismatching printf arguments"? If not, enabled more warnings on gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `%i` to print the `cmd` **you are casting it to `signed int`** as @Mario previously guessed. This is why it is negative.

You need to use `%u` to do the printing for it to remain an `unsigned int`

> d or i - Signed decimal integer
>
> u  - Unsigned decimal integer

(from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

This will work as you would expect.

```
printk ("our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = %d with fd=%i, cmd=%u and arg=%lu \n ", gtuid, fd, cmd, arg);
                                                    ^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

You print with `%i` which converts the argument to a signed int. Print with `%u`.