# Why is a variable declared as an unsigned int generating a negative value?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I wrote this bit of code to learn about bit shifting.  To my surprise, even though I declared `x` to be an `unsigned int`, the output includes a negative number, namely when the leftmost bit is set to 1.  My question:  why?  I thought an `unsigned int` was never negative.  Per `sizeof(x)`, `x` is 4 bytes wide.

Here is the code fragment:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x;

    x = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        printf("2^%i = %i\n", i, x);
        x <<= 1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
2^0 = 1
2^1 = 2
2^2 = 4
2^3 = 8
2^4 = 16
2^5 = 32
2^6 = 64
2^7 = 128
2^8 = 256
2^9 = 512
2^10 = 1024
2^11 = 2048
2^12 = 4096
2^13 = 8192
2^14 = 16384
2^15 = 32768
2^16 = 65536
2^17 = 131072
2^18 = 262144
2^19 = 524288
2^20 = 1048576
2^21 = 2097152
2^22 = 4194304
2^23 = 8388608
2^24 = 16777216
2^25 = 33554432
2^26 = 67108864
2^27 = 134217728
2^28 = 268435456
2^29 = 536870912
2^30 = 1073741824
2^31 = -2147483648
```

Comment: Because you're printing it as a signed value.

Comment: The short answer is because `printf()` does not do any type checking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181691/why-does-printf-show-negative-values-for-unsigned-int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use correct conversion symbol

```
printf("2^%u = %u\n", i, x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `%i` format specifier, which prints its argument as a signed `int`.

If you want to print as unsigned, use the `%u` format specifier.

```
printf("2^%i = %u\n", i, x);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you talk about the sign of a integral value in C (C++ and many other programming languages) you are just talking about how you interpret some data.

You must understand that what's stored inside an `unsigned int` are just bits regardless of the sign, the fact that they behave as "unsigned" when used is a mere interpretation of the value.

So by using `%i` specifier you are treating it as a signed value, regardless how it is declared. Try with `%u` which specifies that you want to treat them as `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ reference page on printf, using %i in the string passed to printf means the corresponding argument will be treated as *signed* decimal integer. This means that your unsigned int will be casted to a signed int.
In C++, casting unsigned to signed (and reverse) only changes the interpretation, not the bit values. So setting the leftmost bit to 1 makes the number negative because that is what it corresponds to in signed integer interpretation.
To achieve the expected number, use %u instead for unsigned integer interpretation.

Comment: Better to use a C reference for C posts than a C++ reference.

Comment: @chux thanks for the suggestion. I'll fix that some time tomorrow.