# How can I print maximum value of an unsigned integer?

Tags: c

I want to print the maximum value of the unsigned integer which is of 4 bytes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned int x = 0xffffffff;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    x=~x;
    printf("%d",x);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get output as -1 and 0. How can I print x = 4294967295?

Comment: use the library `limits.h` (i'm not sure, but it might be a c++ library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int a = 0;
    printf("%u", --a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`4294967295`

How it works is that `0` is the minimum value for `unsigned int` and when you further decrease that value by `1` it wraps around and moves to the highest value.

Answer (score 17):

The `%d` format treats its argument as a *signed* `int`.  Use `%u` instead.

But a better way to get the maximum value of type `unsigned int` is to use the `UINT_MAX` macro. You'll need

```
#include <limits.h>
```

to make it visible.

You can also compute the maximum value of an unsigned type by converting the value -1 to the type.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned int max = -1;
    printf("UINT_MAX = %u = 0x%x\n", UINT_MAX, UINT_MAX);
    printf("max      = %u = 0x%x\n", max, max);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `UINT_MAX` isn't *necessarily* `0xffffffff`. It is if `unsigned int` happens to be 32 bits, but it could be as small as 16 bits; it's 64 bits on a few systems.

Answer (score 15):

Use `%u` as the printf format string.

Answer (score 6):

There is the macro defined in `<limits.h>`: `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 4):

Use *`%u`* as the format string to print `unsigned int`, `%lu` for `unsigned long`, and `%hu` for `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `<stdint.h>` and `<limits.h>` then `INT_MAX` or whatever limit is appropriate for your type.

Answer (score 1):

printf("%u", ~0); //fills up all bits in an unsigned int with 1 and prints the value.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, `%u` is for `unsigned int`, however `~0` is a `signed int`

Comment: @M.M. Simple coercion will do: `printf("==> Converted signed to unsigned int: %u\n", (unsigned int)~0);`

Comment: @JonathanKomar that wouldn't produce the maximum unsigned integer, on a ones complement or sign-magnitude system. It should be `~0u`

Answer (score 1):

Curious and easy way to do this is just

```
printf("%lu",-1);
```

it prints whatever the biggest unsigned in your computer:)